# AWS .pem regenerate file or only allow IP

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have an issue on our AWS instances that we might have to reset the .pem key due to one of our developers leaving. My question is can I just only allow IP addresses to access each instance or will I need to regenerate another .pem key and reinitialise each instance?

Will the first option be enough to prevent access?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can restrict access by IP. See "security groups".

You should update your ssh keys and propagate them to your EC2 instances. Ideally, don't use shared credentials (like ssh keys, AWS console access) because of situations like this.